# Datespinner in Codename one

Tags: codenameone

I already used datespinner in my GUI form for picking date but it's not display in all handset, i tested 8 handset out of this only two handset diaplaydatespinner all other not displaying date spinner but functionality of datespinner working. Please help me resolve this issue or let me know how we can use datespinner correctlly for all handsetin codenameone. I am currently working with android devices.
Regards,
Megha.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be a bit more clear?

I'm assuming the handsets weren't iOS or Android handsets? If so the themes for these handsets don't include the spinner styles since these devices usually don't have a component similar to a spinner. We normally suggest people use the Calendar component on these devices although you can use the Spinner assuming the device is a touch device and you add the proper styles in the theme.